# Change weight/order of exposed filters

Tags: views, 9

I have a view with two exposed filters: one generated using the Views UI, and another filter from custom code.

Can I change the order in which the exposed filters are rendered on the form?

I could not find any property I could use to set the order.

Answer (score 1):

There are some possibilities to accomplish this.

1. Rearrange the filters via the Views UI

   Will not work if you added a filter via custom code.
2. Create a `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter` hook and set the `#weight` property to the filters. Maybe you need to do this for every element because the #weight property is not automatically added to the elements. Instead they are added in the selected order.
3. Add a custom `views-exposed-form--VIEW_ID.html.twig` template and render the elements in the desired order.
   https://makedrupaleasy.com/articles/drupal-8-9-make-beautiful-views-exposed-filters-form-custom-twig-template-and-bootstrap

Comment: Option 2 works thank you